# How to get my program to print out?

Tags: java, string, object, tostring

Having trouble trying to get my program to work for my AP Computer Science class. Comments have been made inside the code to show my problem. Thanks guys/gals.

### **Java Class**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Allosaur extends Dinosaur
{
private boolean hungry;
private String response, answer;
private String Allosaur;

 // Prompt asks for 3 constructors: A Default constructor, a constructor with just a name, and a constructor with a name and hunger "response"

public Allosaur()
{
}

public Allosaur(String name)
{
 Allosaur=name;   
}

public Allosaur(String name, boolean hungry)
{
    Allosaur=name;
    this.hungry=hungry;
}

// Used this method to "find out" whether the dinosaur is hungry or not
public boolean getHunger()

{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you hungry? ");
    response = keyboard.next();
    if(response.equals("Yes"))
    hungry = true;
    else if(!response.equals("Yes"))
    hungry= false;

    return hungry;

}

// Asks us to print out "RRRRRRR" if the dinosaur is NOT hungry and "HUNGRRRRRRRY" if the dinosaur IS hungry   

public String roar()
{
    if(hungry == true)
    answer = "HUNGRRRRRRRY";
    else if(hungry == false)
    answer = "RRRRRRR";

    return answer;
}

//When I use the toString() method in my driver class, none of these pop up, why?

public String toString()
{
    String Dino = super.toString();
    Dino = "The Dinosaur's name is: " + Allosaur;
    Dino += "Is the Dinosaur hungry? :" + getHunger() + "\n" + roar();
    return Dino;

} 

}
```

### And here is my Driver Class:

```
public class DinosaurMain extends Allosaur
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
       Allosaur Dino = new Allosaur("Jacob");
       Dino.toString();

}

}
```

I'm very confused as to why nothing will show up when I run the program.

Comment: Where is print statement. You are creating an object and later invoking `toString()` on it.

Comment: Declaring a field with the same name as its class? That's a new low...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing shows up after the String input is requested because you're simply doing the call in DinosaurMain as `Dino.toString()`.  This just makes the String representation for your object.  It doesn't print that String representation out.  If you were to change it to `System.out.println(Dino.toString());` you would see the result.

Comment: Actually, it should have still printed out something, because the `toString()` method calls `getHunger()` which prints some stuff out.

Comment: Yea it printed out the getHunger() method, but it just stopped after that which was my problem.

Comment: @Sweetcharge OK, that makes sense.  I was getting worried when you said nothing showed up.